# Having problems updating my Zune 80G from 3.1 to 3.4

Tags: windows-7, zune, zune-software

I keep getting an error when trying to update my Zune 80G from 3.1 to 3.4.
I'v tried everything in this microsoft [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/945278)

Error is code is: C00D11CD (800B010E)

Seems to be a pretty popular problem but nothing has worked for me.
Can anyone help?

OS: Windows 7 64bit

Comment: I ended up going to another pc and it updated. I noticed something weird lately. If you download a file from a microsoft site using anything but IE, the download gets corrupted....very suspect.

Comment: are you sure you were trying to update the Zune **software** and not the Zune device's firmware?

Comment: I never said the Zune *software* ...its the firmware.

Comment: okay, just checking...what do you think of my answer? were you trying to upgrade the firmware through the software or what?

Answer (score 0):

*You should be able to just plug in your Zune 80, go into the software, and update it from there, Zune will download and update it for you, no browser required...*

**To update a Zune within the Zune Software:**

Launch Zune Software & plug in Zune. After waiting for Zune to be recognized by the computer, got to (click):

- Settings
- Device
- Player Update

and it will tell you whether or not your Zune is up-to-date, and what the firmware's upgrade number is...

Hope that helps for next time! Enjoy your Zune!